# Generic type 'BallInterface' requires 2 type argument(s)

Tags: typescript

I am learning Typescript and I got this error `Generic type 'BallInterface' requires 2 type argument(s)` at tennisBall.
How can I call the function whose parameter object has more than one generic type?
Why is it throwing an error?
The whole code:

```
const addId = <T extends object>(obj: T) =>{ 
    const id = 3;
    return {
        ...obj,
        id
    }
}

interface BallInterface<T, V>{
    name: string
    data: T
    meta: V
}

const ball: BallInterface<{meta: string}, string> = {
    name: "Tennis",
    data:{meta: "for playing"},
    meta: "Mario"
}

const tennisBall = addId<BallInterface>(ball);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is throwing an error because you defined `BallInterface` as an interface that has two generics.

On the last line, you call `addId` you pass `BallInterface` as generic, without specifying what would `T` and `V` of BallInterface be.

It's not entirely clear what your goal is here. If all you want to achieve is to add the `Id` field, you don't need to pass a generic to `addId` at all. You're making it more difficult than what actually is :)

```
const addId = (obj: object) =>{ 
    const id = 3;
    return {
        ...obj,
        id
    }
}

interface BallInterface<T, V>{
    name: string
    data: T
    meta: V
}

const ball: BallInterface<{meta: string}, string> = {
    name: "Tennis",
    data:{meta: "for playing"},
    meta: "Mario"
}

const tennisBall = addId(ball);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now it doesn't throw an error. But still, I couldn't understand well, I did another interface where I only put one generic, and there when I called addId like this addId<BallInterface>(ball); it doesn't throw an error.